# How to force Delphi's TADOConnection use ansistring for Command?

Tags: delphi, unicode, ado, delphi-10.3-rio, ansistring

I have problem with encoding when I insert into dbf file through ADO.

```
Connecting string: 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties="dBASE IV";Data Source='+extractfilepath(ParamStr(0))+';'+
  'User ID=Admin;Password='
```

In a insert command i'm converting data to certain codepage but in table are landing different bytes. Probably because of unicode strings.

```
insert into someDBFFile (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5)
values(
'ATENEUM SPŁśKA Z OGRANICZONŹ ODPOWIEDZIALNOCIŹ S.K.A.  Wpisana w S†dz',
'ie rej.dla Krakowa-r˘dmiežcie Wydzia’ XI Gospodarczy',
'30-741',
'Krak˘w',
'Nad Drwin† 10, '
)
```

Data after insert into DBF:

ATENEUM SPťKA Z OGRANICZONŤ ODPOWIEDZIALNO?CIŤ S.K.A.  Wpisana w SĹdzie rej.dla Krakowa-?rôdmie§cie Wydzia' XI Gospodarczy
30-741Krakôw
Nad DrwinĹ 10,

Should be as in sample code:

'ATENEUM SPŁśKA Z OGRANICZONŹ ODPOWIEDZIALNOCIŹ S.K.A.  Wpisana w S†dz',
'ie rej.dla Krakowa-r˘dmiežcie Wydzia’ XI Gospodarczy',
'30-741',
'Krak˘w',
'Nad Drwin† 10, '

I tried TADOTable with the same result.

```
tblZAEX.Insert;
 tblZAEX.FindField('NA1').AsAnsiString:=ToMazovia(Copy(TInvoiceHeaderPartiesSummaryB_Name.asansiString,1,70));
 tblZAEX.FindField('NA2').AsAnsiString:=ToMazovia(Copy(TInvoiceHeaderPartiesSummaryB_Name.asansiString,71,70));
 tblZAEX.Post;
```

Comment: Your string constant is Unicode and I highly doubt that the db backend (dbase iV??) is Unicode capable...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26169419/327083